# Can a application swf be reloaded in AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm being plain lazy because I have a basic actionscript AIR application and I'd like to reset it on a button press. By any chance is it possible to somehow tell AIR to reset/reinitialize/reload the application swf ?

I imagine it might possible to initialize a swf again via Loader's loaderBytes method and probably pass bytes from the loadInfo object or simply write a method that loops through the classes and resets them. I was just wondering if the hacky idea mentioned above is achievable, and if so how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks hacky enough, though didn't try myself, yet should work :

```
      navigateToURL(new URLRequest(stage.loaderInfo.url) , "_level0");
```

Taken from [here](http://imagineric.ericd.net/2011/02/07/a-reset-for-your-swf/).

Comment: this looks simple enough, yet, in my application I end up with a blank screen when I do that :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in instaled AIR , it will close Your current app and open new instance :

```
import mx.core.Application;
import mx.core.WindowedApplication;
import adobe.utils.ProductManager;

public function restart():void {
    var app:WindowedApplication = WindowedApplication(Application.application);
    var mgr:ProductManager = new ProductManager("airappinstaller");
    mgr.launch("-launch " + app.nativeApplication.applicationID + " " + app.nativeApplication.publisherID);
    app.close();
}
```

Comment: interesting hack(+1), although it has two drawbacks: it's quitting and relaunching the app (rather than 'refreshing/reloading' the content swf) which is visible, and it depends on the Flex framework